# What is new for developers in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Today was released SQL Server 2008 R2.
Was trying to find what is new (from the developer perspective), but the MS sites has all the PR blah, blah, blah.

There is something new to be aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m running the express version and have noticed very few changes from 2008. The biggest change for express users is the increase in DB limit from 4GB to 10GB which could be very useful for some.

The other point I see pushed a lot is “self service BI” which is something I’m going to be looking into more as a present we use business objects which is good but costly

Comment: The new limit is very useful indeed.